# What would be the value of $P$ in this example?

Tags: random-variables, markov-chains, markov-process

> A Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ has the following transition matrix:
>   $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
>  0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
>  0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
>  0.3&0.2&0.5
>  \end{bmatrix}$$
>   with initial distribution $\alpha = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)$.
>
> Find the following:
>   (a) $P(X_7 = 3|X_6 = 2)$
>   (b) $P(X_9 = 2|X_1 = 2, X5 = 1, X_7 = 3)$
>   (c) $P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1)$

What I understand according to the [Example-$7.16$ of book by Symour Lipchuz (Page-$132$)](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/schaums-probability.pdf) that, $P^n$ is used to find the probabilities of change of states in exactly $n$ steps, and $p^{(m)} \cdot P^n$ is used to find the probability distribution of various states after $m$ steps.

According to my understanding, there are no uses of Initial Distribution in these three computations. Because, multiplication of a $1X3$ and $3X3$ matrices will give a $1X3$ matrix. In that case, the transition matrix won't make sense for three states.

So, my attempted solution is the following:

---

(a) This question actually asks:

> *What is the probability that the system changes from state-$2$ to state-$3$ in exactly $1$ step?*

So, the answer would be $p(2, 3) = 0.6$

(b) This question actually asks:

> *What is the probability that the system changes from state-$3$ to state-$2$ in exactly $2$ steps?*

$$P^2 = P \cdot P = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
 0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
 0.3&0.2&0.5
 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
 0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
 0.3&0.2&0.5
 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
 0.19&0.27&0.54\\
 0.18&0.28&0.54\\
 0.18&0.27&0.55
 \end{bmatrix} $$

So, the answer would be: $p(3, 2) = 0.27$

(c) I think, this question asks:

> *What is the probability that the system changes from state-$1$ to state-$3$ in exactly $9$ steps?*

Is it?  If yes, then it would be $p(1,3)$ from $P^9$.

Am I correct?

---

**Edit:**

$P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_0 = 3, X_1 = 1)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$
$\Rightarrow P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_1 = 1, X_0 = 3)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$
$\Rightarrow P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_1 = 1| X_0 = 3)\cdot P(X_0=3)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$

Now,

- from $P$, we have $P(X_1=1|X_0=3) = 0.30$
- from $\alpha$, we have $P(X_0=3) = 0.50$, and
- from $\alpha P$, we have $P(X_1=1) = 0.17$

So,

$P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{0.30 \cdot 0.50}{0.17}  \approx  0.88$.

Is this a correct calculation?

Comment: At the top, you have for (c) $P(X_0=3 \mid X_1=1)$, but later you talk about 9 steps. Presumably this means that you’re thinking about $X_9$ (in which case it’s really eight steps) or $X_{10}$. Which is it?

Comment: No, they’re not ”changing in reverse order.” The process only goes in one direction. It’s asking you about the probability that the system started in state 3 given that it’s in state 1 after a single step. Why then are you asking about nine steps of the process at the end of your question?

Comment: $X_0$ is the state at time $t=0$; $X_9$ is the state at time $t=9$. You can’t go back to $0$ from $9$.

Comment: It means exactly what I wrote in a previous comment. You’re being asked about the probability of a specific history of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have part (a) and part (b) down. For part (c), we need that initial distribution.

What is the probability that the system is in state 1 after one step?
What is the probability that the system starts in state 3 and is then in state 1 after 1 step?
Can you use these to find the conditional probability this part asks for?

And no, there's no cyclic behavior here. The sequence of $X_n$ keeps going for all positive integers $n$, and it's not periodic.

[In response to the added material in the question]
Yes, that's a correct calculation. You have now fully solved the problem.

Comment: Considering that your claimed answers imply the probability of starting in state 3 and then going to state 1 is less than the probability of going to state 1 regardless of where we started ... no, you've got that part wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to say there. Now, what I was trying to say with the bit that had the word "regardless"? The probability of starting in state 3 and then going to state 1 after one step **must** be $\le$ the probability of being in state 1 after one step.